# VbaCodeCleaner appears as though Focus Rectangle Thicker is checked when it is unchecked

Tags: excel, vba

I’m running Excel 2010 & Excel 2003 on a Windows 10 version 21H2 machine.

I noticed a change in the appearance of Rob Bovey’s VbaCodeCleaner. A thick border appears around whatever has the focus (buttons, tabs, file selection), which makes reading the corresponding text difficult.

[image]

On a different machine running same OS and MS Office versions, everything appears normal.

What I’ve tried:

1. Run a repair on MS Office
2. Downloaded and installed the latest VbaCodeCleaner
3. Searched the internet for a possible Windows setting causing this.

As this is happening on both versions of Excel I suspect this might end up being a Win 10 setting.

UPDATE: I just noticed that this is also happening with the Tools>References dialog.

Comment: Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Ease of Access Centre\Make the computer easier to see and untick make *Focus Rectangle Thicker*.

Comment: Already been there, Focus Rectangle Thicker is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think I may have resolved the problem.  The Focus Rectangle Thicker was already unchecked, so I checked it, Apply, unchecked it and Apply again and voila! So I have no idea what really happened, but toggling that setting seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this weird problem. Hopefully, if it happens to someone else this post would be of help.